# Laravel eloquent hasManyThrough model access

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have three models as following:
-comments
-item that hasMany comments
-list that hasMany items & hasManyThrough('comment','item)
which means i have lists with many items and items with many comments.the comments are linked to lists via hasManyThrough items.
lists are as follows:

```
class List extends Model{
protected $fillable = ['title','description','user_id'];

public function items()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Item');
}

public function comment()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Comment', 'App\Item');
}}
```

items:

```
class Item extends Model
{
    //
    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $fillable = ['title','description','user_id','list_id'];

    public function comment(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }

    public function list(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\List');
    }

}
```

and comments:

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = ['content','item_id','user_id'];
    public function items(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Item');
    }

}
```

How can i access the comments relating to each list?
**EDIT:** when i try to access the comments for a list with id=15 e.g. $list->comments , i get the following error:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'items.list_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `comments`.*, `items`.`list_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `comments` inner join `items` on `items`.`id` = `comments`.`item_id` where `items`.`list_id` = 15)

Comment: Is it not working if you try and access the relationship normally e.g. `$list->comment;`? On a side note, I would recommend using plural names for relationships that return a collection i.e. `comments` instead of `comment`.

Comment: i dont think that would work because there is no list_id in my comments table

Comment: You're using `hasManyThrough` which will essentially get all the `comments` that belongTo `items` which belong to the `List`. Have you tried it and it doesn't work?

Comment: `https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through` check the documentation

Comment: @Rwd yes , i tried but no luck

Comment: I edited the post with the error for list->comments

Comment: Ok, it looks like there isn't a `list_id` on the `items` table which would mean that some of your other relationships won't work either. Please can you add your migrations for these tables.

Comment: HUH! That was it man! thanks for the input :)